# Guidelines for retagging

Tags: discussion, tags, faq-proposed, retagging

Now that I've reached 2k rep, I'd like to help by doing some retagging. There are a number of big tags that get frequently misused, such as [bible](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bible) and [jesus](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jesus). Just because a question is about Christianity doesn't mean that those tags should be used!

I intend to follow the guidelines in [What is our tagging philosophy?](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1429/6071)

Some questions:

1. I might be able to get online a few times a day. How big could a batch of retags be before it unhelpful obscures new questions? 3-5 perhaps?
2. I assume editing on hold questions with better tags can only help. What about closed questions? What about duplicate questions? (It doesn't appear possible for me to edit migrated questions...)
3. Is it okay to retag some of the proposed tag synonyms which haven't been agreed upon yet if they seem straightforward?

Answer (score 4):

To give you responses to your questions

1. yes, that's a good number. The important thing is to respect teh front page and not push stuff down that is new or recently edited. The fact that edits bump is an important part of our peer review process. This mostly depends on the volume of edited posts, if the posts you edit are getting pushed past "the fold" (the first screenful of information), within an hour or so, feel free to push another batch of edits, but if they stay for that hour, best to wait a day or two before doing more edits.
2. note that "On Hold" and "Closed" are exactly the same except that closed questions (except dupes) now show "On Hold" for the first week. In this case I ask you to use your judgement, is the question likely to be reopened, if so, then please edit the tags, if not, then please don't. (If it's egregiously bad, flag it for deletion).
3. Yes. To be honest, we've been lax at implementing these mostly because we don't have people who want to do them. Feel free to retag. If you have a question on a tag, just ask.

Comment: Retagging is kind of like dejunking your Desktop. It needs to be done, but always "later."

Comment: On #2, do you mean that if the question is clearly going to remain closed that bad tags should stay? That could mean that eventually some tags will have more badly tagged closed questions than correctly tagged good ones.

Comment: @curiousdannii if that ever becomes the case, we probably need to kill the tag. That's a meta discussion to have.

Comment: Don't kill Jesus!